Contribution of sum of random numbers
Trying to find a way to do this without just having a huge lookup table.
Sum 6 random number (11 to 255), and find the chance that one of the numbers is contributing more/less than a chosen amount of the total. Also if possible want to know about pairs, as in do number 3 and 5 contribute less than 20% of the total.
pastebin.com/SNLeSCE2 exact function I want to find the result for

Your question is unclear and ambiguous.  Could you perhaps provide concrete examples of "one of the numbers is contributing more/less than a chosen amount of the total"?

assuming the total is 21, I want to know the chance that one of the random numbers was at least 8 of the total 21 without just having a look up table.

Thank you -- that helps (even though the values you give in the example are impossible, the concept looks clear).  But do you want to frame the question in terms of a percentage of the total, as stated in the question, or in terms of specific values, as stated in your comment?  Those are different questions (and one is easier to answer than the other).
